# Mocked method being called, but Verify returns false

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, moq, xunit.net

Using Moq, I have a method that is being called but the Verify in the test fails stating it isn't. Confused as it seems that there is one invocation in the mock object. Stepping through debugging, the code makes it to the method in question.

the code in the test

```
[Fact]
public async Task WhenUsernameAndPasswordAreEmpty_ThenDisplayErrorMessage() {
     mockAuthenticationService.Setup(mock => mock.SignInAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Throws(new NullReferenceException());

     var loginMessageReceived = false;

     mockAppService.Setup(mock => mock.IsBusy).Returns(false);
     mockLoginViewModel.Object.Username = string.Empty;
     mockLoginViewModel.Object.Password = string.Empty;

     MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LoginViewModel>(this, "LoginSuccessful", (obj) => {
          loginMessageReceived = true;
     });

     await mockLoginViewModel.Object.LoginCommand.ExecuteAsync();

     Equals(loginMessageReceived, false);
     mockAuthenticationService.Verify(auth => auth.SignInAsync(string.Empty, string.Empty), Times.Once());
     mockMessageService.Verify(msg => msg.DisplayLoginError(new Exception("You must enter both a username and password to login.")), Times.Once());
}
```

the code that is being called

```
 catch (NullReferenceException ex) {
     _messageService.DisplayLoginError(new Exception("You must enter both a username and password to login."));
     var properties = new Dictionary<string, string> {
           { "ExecuteLoginCommand", "You must enter both a username and password to login." },
           { "Username", Username },
           { "Password", Password }
     };
                Crashes.TrackError(ex, properties);
 }
```

[image: debug view of mock object]
[image: test output]

Appreciate any guidance

Comment: Of course, the `Exception` instance which you passed to `Verify` is not the same *instance* as was passed to `DisplayLoginError`.

Comment: @canton7 ok, so I see what you are saying, but being new to Moq, how would I test to see what input parameter the method was called with?

Comment: Set up an expectation, which captures the exception in question. Then run some assertions on it, e.g. check its `Message`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks in part to @canton7 I figured it out. Had to do some searching, but figured out how.

The `Verify` needed to take any type of `Exception` and then I can check the property there.

```
mockMessageService.Verify(msg => 
    msg.DisplayLoginError(It.Is<Exception>(ex => 
        ex.Message == "You must enter both a username and password to login."
    ))
    , Times.Once()
);
```

Comment: That's better than my suggestion, nice find!

Comment: @Shaggy13spe this should be of some help with getting up to speed with Moq https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: Could you please mark your reply as an answer so that others who has similar  question could get help from your answer?

Comment: Sorry @JessieZhang-MSFT, had to wait at least one day before it would let me and I forgot about it